# Line Breaks in csv file are causing issues

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing, newline

I am trying to import data from a master .csv file to display on a website using html bootstrap and Javascript. Users can search through this .csv file by keyword and should see rows containing that keyword. All of that works, however the issue is the .csv file has new lines in certain cells. When I attempt to read in that information to the site, instead of the data remaining in the column, it puts it in a new row under the wrong column.. I have spent the best part of 2 weeks trying to solve this on my own (undergrad) and haven't been able to find a solution.

First time posting on StackOverflow and hoping for some expertise. Client does not want to reformat the csv file info to remove new-lines, so without coming up with a new source file type, Im at at loss. Thank you!

I've tried changing the delimiter on the .csv file and that didn't seem to work..

--Edit--

For example, my CSV file is setup similar to this:

[image]

^ The Entry data after the new line that was copy&pasted from a pdf by my client, now displays under 'Title' instead of just under Entry.

-Again, new to stack overflow. First time user. Sorry if I am not doing the best here. Just trying to figure out if there is an html solution to this. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Parse the CSV into memory, then search on it. Use something like [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/).

Comment: and where is your [mcve]?

Comment: What are you using to parse the CSV?

Comment: Papa Parse did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a library like [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/):

```js
const { parse, unparse } = Papa;

const csvString = `
1,"Hello World",true,
2,"World",true,
3,"Hello",true,
4,"Hello
World",true,
5,"Foo",true,
`;

// Parse CSV into data matrix
const { data } = parse(csvString, {});

// Search all rows for columns containing the query
const search = (data, query) =>
  data.filter(row => row.some(col => col.includes(query)));

// Convert the results back into CSV
const results = unparse(search(data, 'World'));

// Show the processed CSV data
console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.2/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: nice parser, had no idea... will try on an existing project 